# Can an HTML5 web page be protected from user text containing unterminated tags?

Tags: html, tags

My website allows users to embellish their text with simple HTML tags like <b>, <i> and a small handful of other reasonably innocuous tags.  All other tags are disallowed (disabled programmatically by replacing the "<" character with &lt; when the input form is processed). User's uploaded text is interspersed on the resulting page. For example, as captions on images. For the most part, this works out well.

Problem arises when user forgets to terminate, say, italicized text with the closing </i> tag. They seem to survive past the end of <span>, <div> and <td> elements. An unclosed <i> causes all text in the rest of the page, user or system text, to be italicised.

I don't look forward to writing code to parse the text to keep track of tags and close them if the user forgot. My question is: does HTML5 have a simple way to declare that any open tag is now closed going forward?

N.B.: A decade ago IE and Chrome were autoterminating unterminated formatting tags at the end of each </td>. Not any more.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, if a tag is left open, it can cause problems with the rest of the code. This is because when reaching massive amounts of code, or nested tags, it would be impossible to determine what and where exactly the developer would want to place the closing tag automatically. 
To handle this, you can use an IDE like [Atom](https://atom.io/) (good for beginners), VS Code, or Sublime, so while typing in the tag, you can press enter or tab to automatically create the opening and closing ones.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Intellij idea IDE. If open tag is created by user closing tag will generate automatic by IDE(Intellij idea).when you press the tad button closing tag is automatically  generate the closing tags.